# Comparison between two Kinetic.Shape

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, kineticjs

i want to do Comparison between two Kinetic Shapes:

this is my code:

```
//  -- self.group = Kinetic.Group() With 10 Shapes
//New Group
var Ngroup = new Kinetic.Group(); 
//ss New Shape
var ss = new Kinetic.Shape(); 
//Insert Current Shape Into ss
ss = getShape(t); 

// Checking If current shape exist in self.group
for(var s in self.group) {

//Check If s = ss <---

if(ss == s){

//Add The Shape to new group
alert("Found");
Ngroup.add(ss);

} else {

//Add the Old Shape to the new group
Ngroup.add(s);

}
}
```

this code is not working
how can i compare between two shapes?

Comment: I think you have to figure out what you mean by "==" for two "Shape" objects. Is a red triangle == to a blue one if they're the same size? What if they're at different positions?

Comment: how can i get the shape position?

Comment: I think there's an API on the parent class ("Node").  I'm just [browsing the documentation](http://kineticjs.com/docs/); I'm not an expert with the library.

Comment: Hmm the API docs are kind-of minimal.  There's a "getPosition()" function but the return value is not described.

Answer (score 0):

These is no == for such complex objects, you have to look at each attribute separately for comparison.

Like:

```
 shape1.getWidth() == shape2.getWidth() // will work as a comparison      
 shape1.getHeight() == shape2.getHeight() // will work as a comparison      
 shape1.getX() == shape2.getX() // will work as a comparison      
 shape1.getY() == shape2.getY() // will work as a comparison    
 shape1 == shape2 //will not work as the objects are not the same object. Even the z-index is different.
```

all the attributes are listed in the documentation with the corresponding functions: http://kineticjs.com/docs/symbols/Kinetic.Node.php